# How come DbContext implements IObjectContextAdapter but doesn't have public ObjectContext property

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext, interface-implementation

In entity framework, the DbContext class implements IObjectContextAdapter interface. When I look inside this interface I see there's only one property

```
ObjectContext ObjectContext {get;}
```

But DbContext class itself doesn't have that property. Now:

1. How does it work? Shouldn't compiler force the DbContext class to have public ObjectContext property?
2. Or put it another way: Why do I have to cast DbContext to ObjectContextAdapter to get access to ObjectContext property.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example of explicit interface implementation.

So to theoretically understand it see this example

```
interface IExplicit
{
    void Explicit();
}

class Test : IExplicit
{
    void IExplicit.Explicit()
    {
     //some implementation goes here
    }
}
```

Now we can instantiate a new `Test()`, but to access the `IExplicit` implementation we have to cast the type like

```
var testobj = new Test();

**will throw Compile time error.
testobj.Explicit();

**We can do.
((IExplicit)testobj).Explicit();
```

so now coming to your actual implementation of `dbcontext`

> **DbContext implemented that property explicitly.So instance will have to be casted to its interface in order to be accessible**.

```
public class DbContext : IObjectContextAdapter
{
    ObjectContext IObjectContextAdapter.ObjectContext 
    {
     get
        { 
         ... 
        }
    }
}
```

You can find the explicit interface documentation here on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx).

Comment: Hmm, this way I discovered that there's a notion of Explicit interface implementation. Thank you.